# jquery progressbar with php variables

Tags: php, jquery, variables, progress-bar

I would like to ask how can i use my own values for progress bar which will show how much credit u spent until your preset maximum budget?
input types are text to see if value comes in. it does. Progress bar has some progress but that is because i manually entered both values. 
http://postimg.org/image/fbjnrvvgn/

CODE:

```
<input type="text" id="max_budget" value="<?php include_once 'budget_calc.php'; echo $max_budget_echo; ?>">
<input type="text" id="calculated_budget" value="<?php include_once 'budget_calc.php'; echo $total ?>">
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
  max: 1000,
  value: 100
});
});
</script>
<div id="progressbar"></div>
```

I would like to have max from user set max in database and value calculated from $total=$i-$o,
like this:

```
 <script>
$(function() {
$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
 max: $('#max_budget').val(),
  value: $('calculated_budget').val()
});
});
</script>
```

I have also tired this:

```
<script>
var max_budget=<?php include_once 'budget_calc.php'; echo $max_budget_echo; ?>
var calculated_budget=<?php include_once 'budget_calc.php'; echo $total; ?>
$(function() {
$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
max: max_budget,
value: calculated_budget
});
});
</script>
```

But nothig works :(
How can i solve this problem?
Thank you for your time (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you just 'echo' them where you need them?

```
<?php include_once 'budget_calc.php'; ?>
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
max: <?php echo $max_budget_echo; ?>,
value: <?php echo $total; ?>
});
});
</script>
```

If this wont work, check your HTML/JS-Code.

Answer (score 0):

Hi your includes will be at the top of the php file. Like this

```
<?php include_once 'budget_calc.php'; ?>

<input type="text" id="max_budget" value="<?php echo $max_budget_echo; ?>">
<input type="text" id="calculated_budget" value="<?php echo $total; ?>">
<div id="progressbar"></div>

<script>
$(function() {
$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
  max: $('#max_budget').val(),
  value: $('#calculated_budget').val()
});
});
</script>
```

This will work. Also the second solution could be.

```
<?php include_once 'budget_calc.php'; ?>
<script>
var max_budget = "<?php echo $max_budget_echo; ?>";
var calculated_budget = "<?php echo $total; ?>";
$(function() {
$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
max: max_budget,
value: calculated_budget
});
});
</script>
```

Make sure you have the $max_budget_echo and $total in the file budget_calc.php. Hope this will help solve the issue.